# I am seeing the long lines of "Y" in putty terminal after git commit

Tags: linux, git, putty, bitbucket

I have commited the first time in git on my linux box.
I have also added the remote repo to the Bit bucket account.

When i hit the `git commit` then for last 40 minutes i am seeing the continuous line of y like this

```
y
y
y
y
y
```

in my putty terminal. i want to know that is that normal or i should break the operation

Comment: Did you perhaps type "yes" at a command prompt?

Comment: That is not normal. You should have killed it 39 minutes and 59 seconds ago.

Comment: Why -ve vote for this , that was my genuine problem

Comment: So, I wondered why I get all those 'y's if I accidentally type y.  This is the first time I googled it however, and this answer came up first thing.  Isn't that partially what StackOverflow should be for???  Great question/great answer.  Not sure why it got negative votes...  +1 from me for both!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At any point did you happen to type "yes"?  There's a utility called `yes` that simply prints `y` over and over again.  It's used to automate utilities that say "are you sure? (y/n)".  It's possible that you accidentally typed "yes" at some point and your system diligently ran `yes` after `git` returned.

Hitting Ctrl-C should break out of it.

Comment: i think you are right , i typed yes there. now i have cancelled it. thanks. With u guys around . i never feel in problem